# PowerMocking a method and trying to get the result of what this method results

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

I am trying to PowerMock a method I'm testing.

What I know about this method: It is taking 5 arguments, from which I can have an impact and I want to test 3 of them. Two other arguments HAVE to be given explicitly.

Other important information - this method is returning a `List`, but a little twisted one, like:

`public static final <T extends SomeInterface> List<T> getComponents(arg,arg,arg,arg,arg)`

But this will work:

`List list = ListFetcher.getComponents(arg,arg,arg,arg,arg)`

Now for the mocking. For now it is looking like this:

```
private ListFetcher mockListFetcher(Date dateFrom, Date dateTo, ComponentContext context) throws ThisAppBusinessException {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ListFetcher.class);
    PowerMockito.when(ListFetcher.getComponents(ExplicitlyGivenString1, context, dateFrom, dateTo, ExplicitlyGivenString2)).thenAnswer(
            new Answer() {
                @Override
                public List answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                    Object[] arg = invocation.getArguments();
                    return (List)(Object) arg;
                }
              });
    return null;
}
```

Eclipse is burning RED when I'm trying to have the results as a `List`.

When I use the construction `return (List)(Object) arg;` there are no warnings or errors in Eclipse, but when I am trying to run the test I get:

`java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to java.util.List`

The second thing is that I am not sure if my approach is any good...

Thanks for ANY advices or answers!

Comment: Sorry, but your question does not compile. You are casting an Array of Objects to a List of SomeInterface. Of course this doesn't work. Can you please rephrase "from which I can have an impact and I want to test 3 of them. Two other arguments HAVE to be given explicitly."? At least to me, it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: The method I'm testing looks like this: `getComponents(String name, ComponentContext context, Date dateFrom, Date dateTo, String pStatus)` - `String name` and `String pStatus` are ALLWAYS the same in my case. There are few other implementations of this method in the class `ComponentsFetcher` so I have to point at exactly the method I need to test... Or at least I think so.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `return Arrays.asList(arg);`?

Comment: So what shoud your mock return?

Comment: "I am trying to PowerMock a method I'm testing." - you either test the real implementation or you mock the dependency that is used by the implementation. You don't mock something that you want to test.